# Convert text (12.05.79) to date in excel

Tags: excel, date, spreadsheet

I have imported some dates into an excel document and I need to format them as dates not text strings.

The format is like this: `12.05.79` but when I set the format to date excel doesn't do anything.

Any way to do this?

C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible ways to convert "in situ" without an extra column

1 - use "Text to columns"

Select column of dates then Data > text to columns > Next > Next > "under column data format" select "Date" and the format from dropdown (MDY or DMY) > OK

2 - use Edit/Replace. Replace "." with "/" (in both cases without quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the format doesn't change the value (or in this case text). You'll have to use a macro, or just use a helper column with the following formula. You can then copy / paste values and remove the first column

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/"))
```