# Converting a string to a date in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I have a column with date values in the format `dd mmm yyyy`. For example, "22 Feb 2014". The month is a string. Is there any way I can convert it to an Excel date?

What I really want to do is count the dates that fall in individual months. That is count how many entries in January, how many in February, etc.

Is there any way I can do it without having to change the existing date value format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if dates are strings you can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(MID(A1:A10;4;3)="Feb"))
```

In the example dates (strings) are in A1:A10 and you want to know how many Feb

or use

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10;"*Feb*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=DATEVALUE(A1)
```

Then you can extract a month from this:

```
=MONTH(B1)
```

Then you can count entries for every month:

```
=COUNTIF($C:$C,2)
=COUNTIF($C:$C,3)
....
```

Comment: Thank you Taosique. But DATE gives me an #VALUE error.

Comment: That's most likely because your regional settings don't match your date format. Go to Control Panel / Region and Language and check the language / date format settings. Your date format in example should 100% match "English (United Kingdom)".

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to count entries group by month and don't need to deal with the real date then just use another column for month

For example in column A there are the dates string in form "dd mmm yyyy". In column B you can use the formula

```
=MID(A1, 3, 3)
```

to extract the month, then use autofilter/sort to rearrange the tables according to column B and count. After that if you don't need column B you can hide it away

If you need the date value then use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379544/995714)